# RuntimeError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from http://www.nvidia.com/

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0, bert-language-model, pytorch-dataloader

```py
n_epochs = 6
model = CNN_Text()
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='sum')
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, model.parameters()), lr=0.001)
model.cuda()

# Load train and test in CUDA Memory
x_train = torch.tensor(train_X, dtype=torch.long).cuda()
y_train = torch.tensor(train_y, dtype=torch.long).cuda()
x_cv = torch.tensor(test_X, dtype=torch.long).cuda()
y_cv = torch.tensor(test_y, dtype=torch.long).cuda()

# Create Torch datasets
train = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(x_train, y_train)
valid = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(x_cv, y_cv)

# Create Data Loaders
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
valid_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(valid, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False)

train_loss = []
valid_loss = []

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    start_time = time.time()
    # Set model to train configuration
    model.train()
    avg_loss = 0.  
    for i, (x_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # Predict/Forward Pass
        y_pred = model(x_batch)
        # Compute loss
        loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_batch)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        avg_loss += loss.item() / len(train_loader)
    
    # Set model to validation configuration -Doesn't get trained here
    model.eval()        
    avg_val_loss = 0.
    val_preds = np.zeros((len(x_cv),len(le.classes_)))
    
    for i, (x_batch, y_batch) in enumerate(valid_loader):
        y_pred = model(x_batch).detach()
        avg_val_loss += loss_fn(y_pred, y_batch).item() / len(valid_loader)
        # keep/store predictions
        val_preds[i * batch_size:(i+1) * batch_size] =F.softmax(y_pred).cpu().numpy()
    
    # Check Accuracy
    val_accuracy = sum(val_preds.argmax(axis=1)==test_y)/len(test_y)
    train_loss.append(avg_loss)
    valid_loss.append(avg_val_loss)
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time 
    print('Epoch {}/{} \t loss={:.4f} \t val_loss={:.4f}  \t val_acc={:.4f}  \t time={:.2f}s'.format(
                epoch + 1, n_epochs, avg_loss, avg_val_loss, val_accuracy, elapsed_time))
```

0

I am facing issue while loading the model using torch which was trained using GPU, I am trying to load that model using CPU. however I am successfully able to load the model but while predicting the results I am getting error. However if I use GPU machine I am able to predict the output but not on the CPU. so plz can some one tell me to access the Nvidia virtual driver.

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-97dcc4989caf> in <module>
      3 loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='sum')
      4 optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(filter(lambda p: p.requires_grad, model.parameters()), lr=0.001)
----> 5 model.cuda()
      6 
      7 # Load train and test in CUDA Memory

RuntimeError: Found no NVIDIA driver on your system. Please check that you have an NVIDIA GPU and installed a driver from http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx
```